# Get selected checkbox using id or name

Tags: jquery

I'm using this code to get all the selected checkboxes. My problem is it loops through all checkboxes. How to only loop by checkbox id or name?

```
$('input.form-check-input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {}
```

Comment: Add `[name="selectedname"]` to the selector.

Comment: IDs must be unique, there's no need to loop over an ID.

Comment: @Barmar How to add selector? I've tried `$('input.form-check-input:checkbox:checked:name="flexCheck"').each(function() {}` and `$('input.form-check-input:checkbox:checked:[name="flexCheck"]').each(function() {}` but its not working.

Comment: The second should work. Please post a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

That would give you a lot of pain. Instead set id numbers for each of them. And then try to get their value with `.val()` since you are using jquery. A checked one will return some value other wise it will not.